# How to delete captured video from sdcard in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 1;
    public static TextView output;
    private VideoView videoPreview;
    String[] fileList;
    public static MainActivity ActivityContext =null;
    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
    private static File mediaStorageDir;

    private ImageButton deletbtn, previewbtn, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRecordVideo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        previewbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previewbtn);
        deletbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deletbtn);

        /*
         * Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });

        previewbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                previewVideo();
            }
        });

        deletbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                deleteVideo();
            }
        });

        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Recording video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 180);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
        // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);

    }


    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                //previewVideo();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Video recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){

        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        // Check that the SDCard is mounted
        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"MyCameraVideo");


        // Create the storage directory(MyCameraVideo) if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){

            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){

                output.setText("Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");

                Toast.makeText(ActivityContext, "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("MyCameraVideo", "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }

    private void deleteVideo( ) {



enter code here

        File videoFiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyCameraVideo");

        if(videoFiles.isDirectory())
        {
            fileList=videoFiles.list();
            Log.d("hello",FileList );
        }

        for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++)
        {
            Log.e("Video:"+i+" File name",fileList[i]);
        }

      }
    }
```

I am getting this issue.
please suggest me how to do this.

> 8868-8868/com.example.video.videoapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41016ae0)
>   01-22 15:19:33.519    8868-8868/com.example.video.videoapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.video.videoapp.MainActivity.deleteVideo(MainActivity.java:238)
>               at com.example.video.videoapp.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:23)
>               at com.example.video.videoapp.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4278)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17429)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-22 15:19:38.454    8868-8868/com.example.video.videoapp I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 8868 SIG: 9

Comment: point out the line number 228 in your (MainActivity.java), or post as a comment.

Comment: File videoFiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"MyCameraVideo");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File videofiles=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyCameraVideo.mp4");

videofiles.delete();
```

Comment: give the path correctly its deleting for me, path should be like this  "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/temp.3gp" and also dont forget to add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, andandroid.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  these two permission in manifest file.

Comment: This one is worked for me!!!!!                                                                   private void deleteVideo( ) {

        try
        {

            File videofiles=new File(fileUri.getPath());
            if(videofiles.exists())
            {
                videofiles.delete();
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have video to delete",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

Answer (score 1):

Using file class you can do it

```
File file = new File(path_to_the_file);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

where path_to_the_fileis the path of the file you want to delete - for example:

```
/sdcard/YourDirectoryname/filename.extention
```

Comment: This one is worked for me!!!!!                                                                    private void deleteVideo( ) {
        try
        {

            File videofiles=new File(fileUri.getPath());
            if(videofiles.exists())
            {
                videofiles.delete();
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have video to delete",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't delete the file. You are just taking the files inside your `MyCameraVideo` folder. Use the below code to delete the files.

```
    private void deleteVideo( ) {
    File videoFiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyCameraVideo/");

    if(videoFiles.isDirectory())
    {
        fileList=videoFiles.list();
        Log.d("hello",fileList.toString());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++)
    {
        Log.e("Video:"+i+" File name",fileList[i]);
        String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyCameraVideo/"+fileList[i];
        File file = new File(path);
        file.delete();
    }
  }
```

Don't Forget to add these permissions in your Manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When Control is in onActivityResult, you can get the File path and with that you can delete the file if exist.
Review the code, hope it will help you.

Intent to Video Camera

```
intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,
                MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        long maxVideoSize = 15*1024*1024; // 15 MB
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, maxVideoSize);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAMERA);
```

Code in onActivityResult:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAMERA) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("In video from camera", "In video from camera");
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(videoUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            String mMediaFilePath = filePath;   //File path of Video Recorded.

            cursor.close();

        //Delete File from Location.
         File videoFile = new File(mMediaFilePath);
                    if(videoFile.exists())
                    {
                        videoFile.delete();
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one is worked for me@Anuj Sharma                                          private void deleteVideo( ) {

        try
        {

            File videofiles=new File(fileUri.getPath());
            if(videofiles.exists())
            {
                videofiles.delete();
            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have video to delete",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }